# How to convert a python post request to a Postman POST request

Tags: python, flask, postman

I have a python post request to a server where my flask app is hosted. It works fine and I am able to get the desired data.

But I want to test the API using POSTMAN. I am unable to do that because I am unfamiliar with POSTMAN to some extent.

Below is the python code that I have.

```
import requests
import ast
import json

resp1 = {}
url = 'http://myflaskapiurl:port/route'
files = {'file': open(r'file that should be uploaded to the server', 'rb')}
r = requests.post(url, files=files, data={"flag":2})
headers = {
    'content-type': "multipart/form-data",
    'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
}
resp1 = ast.literal_eval(r.text)
print(resp1)
```

I am struggling with the question whether the data and file that I am trying to post to the server should be in raw json or form-data or x-www-form-urlencoded section of body. Also what should be the actual structure.

Because every time I POST this data using form-data or x-www-form-urlencoded section of body I get the error saying

> werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError
>
> werkzeug.exceptions.HTTPException.wrap..newcls: 400 Bad Request: KeyError: 'file'

Comment: What is the purpose of the `headers` variable? `requests` automatically sets `multipart/form-data` when you submit files. (Otherwise no file names can be transmitted.) Also, why does it contain `content-type` twice?

Comment: The issue is not with the code, as I said it working perfectly. I am getting the desired output. And as for the double content-type is concerned I put it there to show that I have tried both of them. I have tried form-data and x-www-form-urlencoded. Both way I am able to send the post request to the server and receive the correct response.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should look like:

[image: POST http://myflaskapiurl:port/route with form-data body params "flag: 2" and "file: Sample.txt"]

The "params" tab should be empty, maybe you're adding a second `file` parameter there?

Comment: I have tried that but still it gives the same error.